# Metodos sin cuerpo java

Tags: java, herencia

Tengo una clase Animal que hereda de una clase abstracta llamada item que implementa una interfaz quedando todo asi:

Clase Item:

```
public abstract  class Item implements Movable {


private static int nextId = 0;
private double xCoord, yCoord; //location
private double length, height; // define size of item
private String spriteImage;
private Tank tank;
private String id;


protected Item(double xCoord, double yCoord, String spriteImage, double length, double height,  Tank tank) throws ItemException {
    setId("I"+nextId); 
    nextId++;   
    setLocation(xCoord,yCoord);
    setSpriteImage(spriteImage);        
    setLength(length);
    setHeight(height);      
    setTank(tank);
}
  //getter y setter...
```

Clase Animal:

```
public class Animal extends Item implements Movable{

String gender="";
int age,energy=100,limIzq=Movable.TANK_PANE_WIDTH/2-1;;
boolean facingRight;
double speed,requiredFoodQuantity,thresholdReverse;
AnimalStatus status;
double nuevoXL=getXCoord(),nuevoXR=getXCoord(),nuevoYUP=getYCoord(),nuevoYDO=getYCoord(),anteriorXL,anteriorXR,anteriorYUP,comproLimit=limIzq-nuevoXL;


protected Animal(double xCoord, double yCoord, String spriteImage, double length, double height,String gender,int age,double speed,
    double requiredFoodQuantity,double thresholdReverse,int energy,Tank tank)
        throws Exception {
    super(xCoord, yCoord, spriteImage, length, height, tank);
    setGender(gender);
    setAge(age);
    setSpeed(speed);
    setRequiredFoodQuantity(requiredFoodQuantity);
    setThresholdReverse(thresholdReverse);
    setEnergy(energy);
    setStatus(status);

}
 //getter y setter...
```

El caso es que se me pide que incluya dos metodos SIN cuerpo en la clase Animal y no se me ocurre como, ya que si pongo los metodos sin cuerpo logicamente el eclipse me dice que tienen que ser abstractos y si los hago abstractos convierto esa clase en abstraca y ya no puedo crear objetos de ella y quiero seguir pudiendo hacerlo...

Hay alguna manera tal y como esta montado, de poder incluir esos dos metodos que me piden,sin cuerpo en la clase animal?

Ya pobre en meterlos en la clase item,que esa es abstraca pero luego ya que la clase Animal hereda de Item,me pide que los incluya,logico,y les añade cuerpo.

Los metodos serian:

```
public int loquesea();
public void loquesea();
```

Comment: Una clase que es abstracta no se puede instanciar. Si un método "sin cuerpo" significa abstracto, eso convierte a la clase en abstracta y por lo tanto no la podrás instanciar. Así que no, no se puede hacer lo que quieres. Otra cosa, no entiendo por qué implementas `Movable` en `Animal` si `Animal` extiende a `Item` y `Item` ya lo hace.

Comment: Respecto a lo que me dices de Animal,es cierto,realmente me di cuenta hace nada.Sobre el otro tema entonces no se como implementar esos dos metodos que me piden sin cuerpo en Animal...Me tiene muy confundido,ya que debo seguir creando objetos de Animal...asi que...como poner esos dos metodos sin cuerpo dentro de animal?

Comment: No se si sea algún ejercicio que estés haciendo pero eso que quieres hacer no es posible. Una clase concreta no puede contener métodos sin implementar.

Comment: ¿No séra que no estás interpretando bien lo que te piden? Creo que lo que tienes que hacer es implementar (es decir, añadir el código) los dos métodos que Animal está obligado a tener para cumplir con Movable

Comment: @PabloLozano Eso no puede ser ya que la interfaz Movable no tiene esos metodos por lo tanto no me pide el compilador que los incluya en la clase Animal,cosa que ocurriria si los cuerpos estuvieran declarados en Movable...Sinceramente no se que pretenden que haga con esos dos metodos..Algo falla en lo que me piden.

Comment: @GlennSandoval Eso es lo que pienso yo pero me piden exactamente eso:La clase Animal incluirá 2 nuevos métodos públicos que no tendrán
cuerpo (i.e. no escribiremos llaves {} para estos métodos):
getOxygenConsumption (no recibe nada y devuelve un int) y
breathe (no recibe nada y devuelve void).

Comment: Si ese es el caso entonces `Animal` tiene que ser abstracto, por lo tanto no lo podrás instanciar. Tiene que estar mal el enunciado o deberás renunciar a instanciar `Animal` para luego crear subclases de `Animal` e implementar esos dos métodos en las subclases.

Comment: @GlennSandoval efectivamente eso es lo que pienso,tal cual...Voy a ver si me aclaran este punto...Por lo menos se que mis dudas son razonables y que tengo claros los conceptos de herencia e interfaz y demás.